# Django: access model instances

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model called `OrderItem`

```py
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and a model called `Order`

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Now in my `views.py` I have an *OrderItem model* `order` instance. And in my *Order model* I need to set its `order` instance to complete. I'm trying something as follows:

```py
orderID = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=4)
#lets say there are more than one order_id with the value of 4
for order in orderID:
    order = Order.objects.get(id=orderID)
    order.complete=True
    order.save()
```

this code gives me:

```
ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orderID` in your example can be list, possibly of size greater than one.
This makes the following to fail:

```py
orderID=OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=4)
#lets say there are more than one order_id with the value of 4
for order in orderID:
       order = Order.objects.get(id=orderID)  # FAIL: list passed as ID
       order.complete=True
       order.save()
```

You should pass `order` as an argument to `.get()` function or use related model, like

```py
order_items=OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=4)
for order_item in order_items:
       order = order_item.order
       order.complete=True
       order.save()
```

Comment: Even though this is correct it makes no sense to iterate multiple times through same order and resave it (  Each of these order_items has same Order object with id 4 as they are filtered recently)

Comment: I've tried to do minimum changes to original code, but you are right that it is better to load the order instance only once.

Comment: I agree that it makes no sense at all to cycle on OrderItem objects. See my anwser for a simpler and fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
orderID = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=4)
```

Here you are selecting all `OrderItem` instances related to an `Order` with id=4.
Then you are cycling on all `OrderItem` objects and you are trying to set a flag `complete=True` on the order associated to each `OrderItem`.

**But** the query is constructed such as all `OrderItem` instances will be related to the same `Order`. So the following will suffice and it's a single query on the DB:

```
Order.objects.filter(id=4).update(complete=True)
```